# Java HttpsURLConnection and Basic auth is enough secure for man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: java, http

I have to make https request from my Minecraft server to my API in an other server (Https) every 5 minutes to exchange confidential information. Is this java code secure enough against man-in-the-middle attacks ?

Is there a better simple solution to use ?

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.test.com/test.php");
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");

    String API_KEY = "%m7y*!qc#eNWLTj_^zM%^PLuh9HTS-jf_-tcav3_D*P33Sk6Yz!w2Tj8WPDyvC3fSh@AXRQN+wRm+DvE#F@u@h5GSC#USnd9rmWyaNecbW&&azu&JNhtu6!QrG&SU!3h";

    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", API_KEY);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    System.out.println(content.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is, when properly configured.

Just add the certificate of your other server's HTTPS server to the Java truststore and remove all other certificates if not needed.

But to be honest, I think that's a really abstract scenario that someone would undergo the effort to launch a MITM attack against a minecraft server.